# Laravel auto update div contents using ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I got some error when im updating the div content in my laravel project. I use the `setInterval` method. But when i put my route in the load parameter it throws me an error. Can someone know why Im getting this error?

shownews.blade.php

```
   <h4 class="comments-title" > <span class="fas fa-comment-alt"></span>
                    {{$news->comments()->count()}}
                    Comments</h4>
                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px;
                      width: 400px; " id="commentarea" >

                          @foreach($news->comments as $comment)
                            <div class="comment" style="background-color: #f6efef;" >
                          <div class="author-info">
                              <img src={{"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($comment->email))) . "?s=50&d=retro" }} class="author-image" id="image">

                              <div class="author-name">
                                   <h4>{{$comment->name}} </h4>
                                   <p class="author-time"> {{  date('jS F, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="comment-content">
                                    {{$comment->comment}}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          @endforeach
                      </div>
                  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
             setInterval(function() {
              $('#commentarea').load('{{ action('NewsController@showNews') }}');
             }, 1000);
            });
           </script>
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']], function(){
    Route::get('/article/{id}', 'NewsController@showNews')->name('article');

});



//comments
Route::post('comments/{news_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
```

Error Message:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: article] [URI: article/{id}]. (View: D:\coindeoro_admin\adminPanel\resources\views\coin\shownews.blade.php)

Comment: you need to pass id because in you are using parameter in your action route

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear no ? Your controller function is expecting an `$news_id` parameter to work.

Just pass the news ID in your route :

```
$('#commentarea').load('{{ action('NewsController@showNews', ['news_id' => $news->id]) }}');
```

Comment: it throws me an error like this sir. `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' (View: D:\coindeoro_admin\adminPanel\resources\views\coin\shownews.blade.php)` But when i fixed the syntax like this `$('#commentarea').load('{{ action('NewsController@showNews', ['news_id' => $news->getKey()]) }}');` It throws me another error `Call to undefined method stdClass::getKey() `

Comment: It's a simple syntax error .. I missed a `]`, if you use any IDE, you should have been noticed

Comment: even if i added a closing bracket sir it throws me an error `Call to undefined method stdClass::getKey()`

Comment: Your `$news` variable is not a Eloquent Model ? Use `$news->id` if so

Comment: if i use `$news->id` sir my site becomes messy

Comment: I tried the code u edited above sir but my site becomes messy. The contents of the div becomes the whole page and it lags so much